# How to get only the date in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

In MVC, right now in my view data format is: `25/06/1992 12:00:00 AM` But i want only date: `25 jun 1992` in this format

```
string bdate = WMU.DOB.ToShortDateString();
string entrydate = WMU.EntryDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");` for 25 Jun 1992